# Widget issue - Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web

I have imported a theme and all is working well with Wordpress. However, I am trying to add a widget into the footer.php but for some reason this is not displaying.

My footer.php is as follows:-

```
<?php get_sidebar('footer_widget'); ?>
```

And I have added this into functions.php too

```
    function bauhaus_arphabet_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => esc_html__( 'sidebar', 'bauhaus' ),
        'id' => 'bauhaus_sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget sidebar_widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'description' => esc_html__( 'blog sidebar', 'bauhaus' ),
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Footer', 'bauhaus' ),
        'id' => 'footer_widget',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget footer_widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>'
    ));
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is not displaying?

Thank you in advance,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the code with :

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer_widget' ); ?>
```

Comment: Perfect Bhavesh. Thank you!